# undefined reference to error when go call the cython share library

Tags: go, shared-libraries, cython

The source code is very simple, but I can not build the go program.

add.pyx

```
#cython: language_level = 3

def add(int x, int y):

    return x + y

add.h

#ifndef ADD_H

#define ADD_H

int add(int x, int y);

#endif
```

I use the `cython --embed -o add.c add.pyx` to create add.cand use the `gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing  -o libadd.so add.c -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -L/usr/local/lib/ -lpython3.10` to create the libadd.so

main.go

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I.
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -ladd
#include "add.h"
*/
import "C"import "fmt"

func main() {
    a:= C.int(2)
    b:= C.int(3)
    result := C.add(a, b)

// 打印结果fmt.Println(C.int(result))

}
```

when run the `go build -o main main.go`, the following

> error:/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed:
> exit status 1/tmp/go-link-1701847393/000001.o: function
> _cgo_0825df845a61_Cfunc_addTwo' 内: /tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:54:
> add' undefined reference tocollect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I hope the go file can be built, and when I run main, the result 5 will be output.

Comment: Cython generates Python modules that are designed to imported and run with the a Python interpreter. This means you **must** start the interpreter and you **must** use the Python import system on the module. The functions **cannot be treated as standalone functions**

Comment: Read https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/embedding.html carefully and do not skip any steps when making your go program.